# Axios post call through React Native gives Network error for cloud url works for ios and not for android

Tags: axios, react-native

I am trying make a post call through axios in react native. axios.post('https....)
But I get Network error in the console when I run this in Android but the same works in ios

Comment: can i see your snippets and Error?

Comment: Error: Network Error

Comment: This is all I get

Comment: did you add  CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) from backend side?

Comment: Yes added cors in the backend

Comment: what is the android version which you are currently working on?

Comment: am using android Pie(9) on my emulator

Comment: Please put the codebase in to this

Comment: componentDidMount() {
   console.log("Test");
    axios.get('https://...',
    { 'headers': { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded','Accept':'application/json' } }
    )
        .then((response) => 
        {
          console.log("API Res",response.data);
          response.data;
      }).catch(error => console.log("Error",error));
      }

Comment: did you call your API using your PC IP or localhost?

Comment: I've added cloud url to call the API

Answer (score 0):

Change your `AndroidManifest.xml` in order to accept `usesCleartextTraffic="true"` as below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        ...
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        ...>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Because [usesCleartextTraffic](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#usesCleartextTraffic) indicates whether the app intends to use cleartext network traffic, such as cleartext HTTP. The default value for apps that target API level 27 or lower is "true". Apps that target API level 28 or higher default to "false".

If you want to allow `http` for some domains but not other domains you must provide `networkSecurityConfig` file as below.

Goto `android/app/src/main/res/xml` & create `network_security_config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Change your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        ...
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        ...>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Comment: Thanks for the quick help @sDushan but am using expo cli for my app where do I edit the manifest.xml file

Comment: @Bhargavireddy Edit ```AndroidManifest.xml``` not possible with an Expo project. In order to add this permission, you would have to use the Bare workflow.